# problem on setting symfony:sf_sandbox installation failed

Tags: symfony1

im new with symfony....plshelp me how to open the symfony system..

Now i already install symphony version 1.0.0 using the tutorial..

1)When i check at cmd..xampp\php>  php –v and symphony –V all is ok..
But when i check for xampp\htdocs\sf_sandbox> symphony –V(i got this msg...)
**C:\xampp\htdocs\sf_sandbox>symfony -V
'php.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

2)one more problem is when i try run my system at localhost...http://localhost/projects(i got error..)

**Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\config/../lib/symfony/util/sfCore.class.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\apps\index\config\config.php on line 7
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\config/../lib/symfony/util/sfCore.class.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\apps\index\config\config.php on line 7
http://www.programmershere.com/questions-answers/482899-problem-sf_sandbox-installation-failed-check-symfony-v.html#post482904**

Comment: I would highly recommend you install symfony version 1.4 instead of 1.0

Answer (score 2):

It appears that in your sf_sandbox installation, you have an incorrect php.exe path.
Edit the symfony.bat file in you sf_sandbox installation.
you'll  find something like this

```
set PHP_COMMAND=php.exe
```

Replace php.exe with the path of your php.exe file. eg. c:\xampp\php\php.exe

2. Check the symfony path in your project configuration 
   sf_sandbox\config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php

Make sure the first "require_once" is pointing to the correct symfony installation
require_once dirname(**FILE**).'/../lib/symfony/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';

And, symfony is not spelled as symphony. ;)

Comment: Zaza. Chk where you have installed symfony. If you are using sandbox i thk it should be in project/lib/ folder. Thats where it is currently searchin for right now. "C:\xampp\htdocs\projects/lib/symfony/util/sfCore.class.php" . Now if u cant find it there... chk if it is installed anywhere else in your htdocs. If not download it and put it in your project/lib folder.

Comment: One more thing. Please add your comments in this text box below. The place you have been adding is reserved for answers. Let me know if it works